# Getting "Error: spawn C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ENOENT" on vs code while starting run in flutter app

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart

While I am trying to run any flutter app through vscode getting this error i.e., Error: spawn C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe ENOENT
in debug mode as well as non debug mode. I have looked into the path of ComSpec in environment variables, and even deleted the vscode and its setting and reinstalled too, didn't solved the problem.